# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a column of data type `datetime` in my table and I would like to insert a date value from a text box into the table but I am getting this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Here is my code:

```
string prfer_date = txtDT_Particip.Text;
int userId = 0;
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_User"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", txtFName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreferredDateStart", prfer_date.ToString());
        }
     }
 }
```

it is failing at `prfer_date`. Thanks for your help

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I missed in your question is, `prefer_date` is of type string. `AddwithValue` infers type from the field type, so at SQL end it will treat it as `nvarchar` and hence the error. What you need is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PreferredDateStart", SqlDbType.DateTime) 
                            { Value = prefer_date });
```

Or you can parse your string to a DateTime object and then use `AddWithValue` like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PreferredDateStart",DateTime.Parse(prefer_date));
```

Considering that `prefer_date` contains a value that can be successfully parsed by `DateTime.Parse`.

Comment: i have tried the first one and i am still getting error.  The 2nd one it seems they syntax is wrong: {Value = prfer_date);

Comment: @moe are you missing the closing `}` there?

Comment: @moe, noticed that `prefer_date` is already a string. You need to parse it to `DateTime` object to be used with `AddWithValue`, I have fixed the syntax issue, try now.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Datetime has a range of "January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999"

If you do something like this in SQL:

```
select convert(datetime, '1665-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Then you get the error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.